# Pagination for Chart.js line chart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js

So I have tons of data, about 10000 rows of data which all needs to be shown in the line chart somehow. I would like it if there was a pagination system. Like click on an arrow and it shows the next 20 data points etc.

Currently my app just crashes if I try to load all of the 10000 points into the chart. Is there something I can do to prevent this performance issue, lazyload orsmth?

Oh and I'm using chart js and react-chart-js-2

Big thanks ahead

Comment: No it does not support this natively, but you can make it yourself by only loading chart.js with x values and make your own buttons and update the chart data yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @LeeLenalee!

So chart js doesn't have pagination options. What I did was make 2 buttons which onClick show me the next 20 data values or previous 20 data values. I slice the arrays which get sent into the Line chart label, datasets.